# How to remove unwanted text output with shiny rgl

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

With a recent version of the rgl package for R (3.3.1, Windows 10) I am able te create interactive 3D plots in a Shiny app. However, I get lengthy unwanted text output as well.

How can I suppress this output?

Here's code for an example shiny app that results in the unwanted text output:

```
library(shiny) # 0.13.2
library(rgl) # 0.1.0
library(shinyRGL) #0.96.0

aShinyList = list(  
    ui      =   webGLOutput("myWebGL"),
    server  = function(input,output, session)(  output$myWebGL <-    renderWebGL({
    points3d(1:10, 1:10, 1:10)
    axes3d()
  }))
)

runApp(aShinyList)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Mj8.jpg)'s a screenshot of the result I get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `shinyRGL`.  It hasn't been updated in a long time.  `rgl` itself now contains full Shiny support.  See the examples in the directories

```
system.file("shinySimple", package = "rgl")
```

and

```
system.file("shinyDemo", package = "rgl")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.